# HTML / Javascript : Open window in a new context

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I am working on a "Log in as" feature for my website. But the admin panel and the client panel are on the same domain. But the session and authentication cookie is the same and the administrator is logged out after logging into the customer account.

Is there a solution to open a new window with a "new" context, without cookies and local storage?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

your content must be content a tag then your page opens in a new window using Jquery.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(".box").click(function() {   
        strUrl=$(this).find("a").attr("href");       
        window.open(strUrl);return false;         
    });
});
```

Visit this
https://codepen.io/Lucifer18/pen/XWNXYzd

Comment: It does not work. window.open will open the window normally, in a tab with the same context.